# Python JSON Element Access with 2 responses

Tags: python, json, api

I can't find the right search term to come up with an answer to this but I know it's a noob question.  I'm accessing an API which returns either:

```
{  
   "Items":[  
      {  
         "Id":"12",
         "Type":"Address",
         "Highlight":"564754165545",
      }
   ]
}
```

or sometimes:

```
{  
   "Items":[  
      {  
         "Id":"12",
         "Type":"BuildingNumber",
         "Highlight":"145454479854",
      },
      {  
         "Id":"12",
         "Type":"Address",
         "Highlight":"564754165545",
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to get the "highlight" element data but only when type is address from a reply.

Thanks for your help and sorry I couldn't work out the name of the multiple rows to find this for myself.

Answer (score 0):

`Items` is a list of dicts.  According to your example, sometimes the list contains one item, and other times it contains two items.

```
for item in foo['Items']:
    if item['Type'] == 'Address':
        print (item['Highlight'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
new_items = [ j for j in JSON['Items'] if j.get('Type') == 'Address' ] 
JSON = {'Items' : new_items }
```

for only heighlight data

```
new_items = [ j.get('heighlight') for j in JSON['Items'] if j.get('Type') == 'Address' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a list of highlights objects with `Address Type`

```
[highlight for highlight in respose['Items'] if highlight['Type'] == 'Address']
```

Comment: This returns the entire dict; I think he only wanted the single `Highlight` field value.